# MyEclipse builds workspace on saving JSP page every time

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, myeclipse, eclipse-3.2

Whenever I save a jsp page, MyEclipse IDE start building the workspace. It should build when I change in any class file. Or if there are classes that not compiled. But why it start building whole workspace when I change in a JSP file. I am stuck on it. Please advise me on this problem.

I am using MyEclipse 5.5 over Eclipse 3.2

Thanks.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684773/eclipse-builds-all-classes-on-each-save help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is due to problem in java build path, fix your build path and get out of this.

Comment: At my end, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For every JSP, the JSP compiler generates a corresponding Java class.  So when you save a JSP, Eclipse/MyEclipse is figuring that it needs to do a workspace build to 1) run the JSP compiler, and 2) compile the resulting Java class to bytecodes.

I imagine you can modify this behavior (e.g. via Eclipse/MyEclipse preferences), but I don't use MyEclipse, and I don't do J2EE development this way anyway.

Comment: But I dont know why it start building the whole workspace. From the start.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of problem in java build path, fix your build path and get out of this issue.

Answer (score -2):

JSP is a class file. You can write any java code inside it.