# How to ‘partly compile’ Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, build

My Eclipse is configured '*Project*'->'*Build Automatically*'. There are large number of Java files in my project. Once **one** java file is modified, **all** java files are compiled under the project. It spends much time really.

My question is how to configure Eclipse as '**partly compile**' which merely compiles related java files. Does it make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse's 'Build automatically' should only compile files that have changed, and their dependencies. Unless you are changing a class that every other class in your project depends on then Eclipse should not being doing a full build every time. Typically a full build is only necessary when you 'clean' your projects to delete all old class files.

Comment: Once Eclipse has successfully built once, it should do the partial build every time after that.  Sometimes if you have errors on the initial build it conflicts with the partial build...

Comment: Do you use an _Ant Builder_ or just the default _Java Builder_?

Comment: @gawi: 'default Java Builder'. @samkass: Some error in java sources forces to compile ALL java source?

Comment: What make you believe _every_ classes are built?

Comment: @gawi: Thanks for your reminding. I checked last modify time stamp of class files, just ONE class file was updated. But it still spent much time, so I checked 'Progress' view, I guess collection of many error java caused long time in Eclipse.

Comment: @Shengyuan Lu Maybe you should reduce the number of entries in your "Problems" view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some really strange dependencies, it won't compile everything. Eclipse keeps track of the classes each class depends on. If a file changes, it recompiles the classes in it, and any classes that depend on them, and so on. So, often, saving one file will cause compilation of just one class.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude files you don't need from your build: right click on the file in the package explorer,
 choose "Remove from context",  or Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Down

Answer (score 0):

It SHOULD just build your part. If you have Maven plugin going you would need to tweak it's settings to make it not do a full build every time. Ditto for any kind of aspects...

Answer (score 0):

See also the [Eclipse builds ALL classes on each save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684773) question.
I still see this behavior when I do refactoring out of the IDE, eg. deleting classes with Perforce, etc. The fact most of the code must still be compiled with a legacy custom Ant-based builder (eg. to generate query classes, Antlr code, etc.) doesn't help here.